# When re-parametrizing a likelihood function, is it enough just to plug in the transformed variable instead of a change of variables formula?

Tags: regression, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

Suppose that I am trying to re-parametrize a likelihood function that is exponentially distributed. If my original likelihood function is:

$$
p(y \mid \theta) = \theta e^{-\theta y}
$$

and I would like to re-parametrize it using $\phi = \frac{1}{\theta}$, since $\theta$ isn't a random variable, but a parameter, it is enough just to plug-in?

What I mean explicitly is:

$$
p\left(y \mid \phi = \frac{1}{\theta}\right) = \frac{1}{\phi} e^{-\frac{1}{\phi} y}
$$

If so, I am not sure what the theory behind this is. My understanding is that the likelihood function is a function of the parameter, so why I don't need to use a change of variables formula confuses me. Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do not need a Jacobian in your transform because it is a probability distribution on $y$, not on $\theta$. It must integrate to one in $y$, whether you use $\theta$ or $\phi$:
$$
\int p(y|\theta)\text{d}y =  \int p(y|\phi)\text{d}y = 1
$$
It is only when you include a (Bayesian) measure on $\theta$ that the Jacobian appears. That is, if $p(\theta)$ is the prior on $\theta$, then the posterior density of $\theta$ is
$$p(\theta|y)\propto p(\theta) p(y|\theta)$$ and the posterior density of $\phi$ is
$$p(\phi|y)\propto p(y|\phi)p(\phi)=p(y|\theta(\phi))p(\theta(\phi))\left|\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \phi}\right|\propto p(\theta(\phi)|y)\left|\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \phi}\right|$$which does involve the Jacobian $\left|\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \phi}\right|$.

Comment: If I am trying to find $p(\theta|y) \propto p(y|\theta)p(\theta)$, where $\theta = \frac{1}{\phi}$, I know that $p(\theta)$ and $p(\theta|y)$ need the Jacobian, but is this a case where you are saying that I NEED the jacobian for transforming $p(y|\theta)$?

Comment: Even in this case you do not use a Jacobian on the likelihood part.